# How to add option name to the Version option in Click

Tags: python, click

How can I add '-V' as an extra keyword to the "Version" option? I did this with the "Help" option but I couldn't with the "Version".

I have this code:

```
CONTEXT_SETTINGS = dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help']) # Help Parameter Customized
@with_plugins(iter_entry_points('click_command_tree'))
@click.group(cls=HelpColorsGroup,help_headers_color='yellow',help_options_color='cyan', context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS)
@click.version_option('0.01',prog_name='Educational Project' )
```

[image]

Comment: Please refer to the answer accepted for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75447557/how-to-add-another-name-option-for-python-click-version-option