# How to Add Another Name Option for Python click.version_option?

Tags: python, version, python-click

My question is exactly the same as in [How to add option name to the Version option in Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68691821/how-to-add-option-name-to-the-version-option-in-click)

I have the code, and I am able to print out the version of my library using the command "py main.py --version"

See: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.version_option

```
@click.version_option(version=version)
def main():
  pass
```

However, I would like to add another name option "-V", how can I do this? The documentation and codebase doesn't seem to have this option to add another name option like for the --help argument. (See: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.Context.help_option_names)

I have tried to add the "-v" name option in the param_decls, however I get the following error:

[image]

Neither of these work either, since positional arguments can't come after keyword arguments (first line), and I'm not sure why the second line doesn't work:

```
@click.version_option(version=version, "--version", "-V")
@click.version_option("--version", "-V", version=version)
```

Please refer to the answer provided by @aaossa below! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to define additional option names using the positional argument `param_decls` ("One or more option names." according to the [docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.version_option))

Here's an example:

```py
import click

version = "0.0.1"

@click.version_option(version, "--version", "-V")
@click.command()
def main():
  pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. my apologies for not mentioning that I have tried this out before, and I get the error: TypeError: Option.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'param_decls'

Comment: What you added to your question is not the same. `param_decls` are positional arguments, you're passing it as a keyword argument, causing it to receive two different values. Can you try using the exact code from my example (passing everything as positional arguments)?

Comment: Turns out you are right! I have been passing version as keyword arguments all along, so doing @click.version_option(version=version, "--version", "-V") or @click.version_option("--version", "-V", version=version) both produces errors. Thank you so much for answering my question. really appreciate it!